# Change a script src with js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change what js file an element uses at a certain year. Here is what I have so far. When I inspect the page the src changed but it did not affect the element as it's supposed to.

Thanks!

HTML:

```html
<script id="element1" src="#"></script>
<script src="js/element-by-year.js"></script>
```

JS:

```js
var yearly = document.getElementById("element1");

var refreshStatus = () => {
  // Get dates/time/hours
  const today = new Date();
  let year = today.getFullYear();

  if (year == 2022) {
    yearly.src ="js/change1.js";
  } 
  if (year == 2023) {
    yearly.src ="js/change2.js";
  }
}

// run when starting
refreshStatus();

// updates every day
setInterval(refreshStatus, 86400000);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what exactly you're trying to do here? Changing the `src` of a script in response to the passage of an arbitrary amount of time is something that, to me, would indicate a severe design flaw (in that it could be done many other ways of significantly lower complexity than what you're proposing here).

Comment: What is an easier way to get what I want to do? I am not the best at JS. I want something like this.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Changing the `src` is not the goal, it's what you think is a step toward the goal.  What is the actual goal?  What functionality are you trying to build?  If you want to "do something different based on the year" then you would put "something" and "something different" into functions you can call and you would conditionally call one function or the other based on the current year.  None of that would involve "changing the `src`".

Comment: @David I took your advice and made it a function and it works perfectly. Thanks for helping. As per usual, the solution was right under my nose! This is now a tool in my tool belt.

Answer (score 0):

To fix my problem I used functions instead of trying to change the src.

```js
function element1 () {
    alert("It's 2022!");
}

function element2 () {
    alert("It's 2023!");
}

var refreshStatus = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  let year = today.getFullYear();

  if (year == 2022) {
    element1();
  } 
  if (year == 2023) {
    element2();
  }
}

refreshStatus();

setInterval(refreshStatus, 86400000);
```